# faster way to append element without searching for last element with each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of strings that each contain a bootstrap panel that are being returned from a post call. I want to loop through each and append them to the end of a container element 'eventContainer', but I'm looking for a way to do it without doing a search in each loop. Is there a better/faster way of doing this then what I'm doing?

FYI - there's another element at the bottom of the container that isn't a panel

Here is what I'm doing

```js
for (var i = 0; i < response.events.length; i++) {
  $("#eventContainer").find(".panel").last().append(response.events[i]);
}
```

and the eventContainer I'm appending them to looks something like this

```html
<div id="eventsContainer">
<div class="panel panel-default"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default"></div>
...append new panels here
<div id="someotherelement"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var box = $("#eventContainer").find(".panel").last(); box.append.apply(box,response.events);` should do it.

Comment: what does apply do?

Comment: Applies the array (`response.events`) as arguments to the function `.append` with the context `box`.

Comment: will this work even if I have a different element at the end of the container. I'll re post my updated snippet.

Comment: That's fine, because `box` is just the last `.panel` - like it is in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will Work, if you simply store the last panel in a variable and use that when you append your elements. You will have to reverse the order:

```
var $lastPanel = $("#eventContainer").find(".panel").last();
for (var i = response.events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  $lastPanel.append(response.events[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet I have created to add elements to the last sibling:
https://codebrace.com/editor/b013fb1cc

You need to check out [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

insertAfter() is used to add new elements next to each and every siblings,
While append() is normally used to append a new element(child) to the parent selector.

if you want to add array/object of events to the last sibling then here is the code snippet:

(for array of events)
https://codebrace.com/editor/b016bcb47

(for event object)
https://codebrace.com/editor/b016cc929

Comment: so which one is the fastest??

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now as far as speed is concerned, I have created the test case here:https://codebrace.com/editor/b01919386

Comment: So in first two execution both the solutions were executed at the speed of 2ms. But in third execution Your solution was 3ms while mine was 1ms.